# Python3 vs. Python2 signal SIGALRM handling difference

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, exception, timeout, signals

I'm evaluating expressions that may take excessive time. I would like to set up a timeout, for example:

```
def handler(signum, frame):                                                                     
    print("handler called")                                                                     
    raise Exception("timed out")                                                                                                                                       

def eval_wrapped(expr, timeout=1):                                                              
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)                                                      
    signal.alarm(timeout)                                                                       
    eval(expr)                                                                                  
    signal.alarm(0)                                                                             
    return None
```

Running

```
> eval_wrapped("9999**9999**9999")
```

in:

Python2: throws the expected Exception

Python3: prints only "handler called", does not throw Exception

What's up here? How to make the above work in Python3?